# deserialize xml in symfony 4 using JMS Serializer

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to de-serialize the follow XML using JMS Serializer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <people>
   <person>
     <personid>1</personid>
     <personname>Name 1</personname>
   </person>
   <person>
     <personid>2</personid>
      <personname>Name 2</personname>
     </person>
</people>
```

My doubt is: Do i need to create a People Entity or just a Person entity is fine?

**UPDATE**

I have a Person entity and I am trying to get de de-serialized data like this:

```
$xml = "xml_as_a_string";
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$xmlContent = $serializer->deserialize($xml,   
    'ArrayCollection<'.Person::class.'>', 
    'xml');
```

but the `$xmlContent` keeps coming as a empty array.

Comment: it depends on your business logic, but it looks like Person is fine.

Comment: You can create a `Person` model. 'People' can be an array of 'Person' objects.

Comment: [Validating, serialising and mapping XML request to model classes](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oxlj/validating-serialising-and-mapping-xml-request-to-model-classes) should help you.